# cannot get table values in Elastic Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

My database has two tables like

1. **user_manage** structure

```sql
USER_ID     int 
USER_NAME   nvarchar(300)   
PASSWORD    nvarchar(500)   
EMAIL       nvarchar(1500)
```

2. **planner** structure

```sql
PLANNER_ID      int 
CONFERENCE_ID   int 
PLANNER_TITLE   nvarchar(MAX)   
SCHEDULE_DAY    nvarchar(MAX)
```

I can fetch values for the user_manage table through elastic search but I cannot fetch values for the planner table.